# ExtJS setTimeout loop function not working (losing scope) Ext.bind

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I have a `ExtJS` 4.2.1 `Controller` where I fires a function after 1 second using setTimeout:

```
onPrint: function () {
        var me = this;

        // start some stuff here...

        // end some stuff here...

        // wait 1 second and call checkDownloadComplete function
        setTimeout(me.checkDownloadComplete, 1000);

    },
    checkDownloadComplete: function () {
        var me = this;

        // validate stuff here...
        if (something == "true") {

            return;
        }

        // first approach but didn't work (maybe because the scope)
        setTimeout(me.checkDownloadComplete, 1000);

        // sencond approach but didn't work
        Ext.bind(function () {
            setTimeout(checkDownloadComplete, 1000)
        }, me)


    },
```

My first try was to use:

> `setTimeout(me.checkDownloadComplete,1000);` But this didn't work

My second try was to comment the last line, and use Ext.bind:

> 

```
Ext.bind(funciton(){setTimeout(checkDownloadComplete,1000)},me);
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong? Because none of those work to call again a function it self.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I also try this but without success:

```
setTimeout(Ext.bind(checkDownloadComplete,me), 1000);
```

Comment: you should try setTimeout(function(){me.checkDownloadComplete.call(me)}, 1000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to change both `setTimeout` calls to:

```
setTimeout(Ext.bind(me.checkDownloadComplete, me), 200);
```

The problem was that on the first call of the `setTimeout`, the `checkDownloadComplete` scope was changed to a `setTimeout` scope instead of controller scope, so changing both fixed the problem-